# Nginx dynamic location depending on device used

Tags: nginx

What I'm trying to do is to specify the location if the user accessed our website by mobile or by web. This is my configuration on the sites-enabled file:
**PLEASE TAKE NOTE ON THE COMMENT THE LINE THAT IS STARTED BY A SHARP**

```
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
    default 0;
    ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0; # exceptions to the rule
    ~*spider|crawl|slurp|bot 1; # bots
    ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1; # OSes
}

map $is_desktop $is_mobile {
    1 0;
    0 1;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
    }
    access_log /usr/logs/nginx/lion/lion.$year-$month-$day.log;

    if ($is_mobile) {
        location / {
            root /usr/src/app1
    }

    if ($is_desktop) {
        location / {
            root /usr/src/app2;
        }
    }

    error_page  405     =200 $uri;
}
```

**TAKE NOTE THAT THE DOMAIN WILL NOT CHANGE AND SUB-DOMAIN will not be used**

It's like using a different front-end code set to be used to render on the domain depending on the device used. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile nginx with community modules like [device-detection](https://github.com/51Degrees/Device-Detection/tree/master/nginx).

Or you can use the following with if statements.

```
## Testing a user agent using a method that reverts the logic of the
## UA detection. Inspired by notnotmobile.appspot.com.
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
    default 0;
    ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0; # exceptions to the rule
    ~*spider|crawl|slurp|bot 1; # bots
    ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1; # OSes
}

## Revert the logic.
map $is_desktop $is_mobile {
    1 0;
    0 1;
}
```

Please note you should add missing agent strings, and keep it updated regulary.

If example:

```
location / {
    if ($is_mobile) {
        root /usr/src/lion;
    }
    if ($is_desktop) {
        root /usr/src/marty;
    }
}
```

Full config:

```
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
    default 0;
    ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0; # exceptions to the rule
    ~*spider|crawl|slurp|bot 1; # bots
    ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1; # OSes
}

map $is_desktop $is_mobile {
    1 0;
    0 1;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
    }
    access_log /usr/logs/nginx/lion/lion.$year-$month-$day.log;

    location / {

        if ($is_mobile) {

            root /usr/src/app1;
            break;

        }

        if ($is_desktop) {

            root /usr/src/app2;

        }
    }
    error_page  405     =200 $uri;
}
```

Comment: By the way, I would gladly appreciate if you can complete the configuration.. not just a snippet

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.. check my updated code on the question

Comment: Updated the answer and tested it myself.